# MySQL: Selecting each term as a column in a group by statement

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table like this in MySQL:

```
PersonID    id        X
1           1         0
1           2         1
1           3         1
1           4         1
2           1         1
2           2         0
2           3         0
2           4         1
3           1         1
3           2         0
```

Etc. X is binary - either 1 or 0. Just assume it's random.

I want to get a query result like this:

```
PersonID   X1   X2   X3   X4
1          0    1    1    1
2          1    0    0    1
3          1    0    NULL NULL
```

How do I do this? I have tried the following:

```
select 
PersonID, 
case when id = 1 then X else NULL end as X1, 
case when id = 2 then X else NULL end as X2,
et cetera
from table 
group by PersonID
```

Which is obviously wrong and would take forever to write (since I have up to 700 different ids for each person), but it's the best I can think of.

Comment: So you may have 700 different ids `1,2,3...700` ?

Comment: Yes. And 700 different columns. Unwieldy but necessary, unfortunately

Comment: in that case you will need to use dynamic sql to generate the pivot table. Check for mysql dynamic pivot and make sure that your column numbers does not cross 4096

Comment: Issues of data display are solved at the application layer/ presentation level code

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an aggregation functions.  For four columns:

```
select PersonID, 
       max(case when id = 1 then X else NULL end) as X1, 
       max(case when id = 2 then X else NULL end) as X2,
       max(case when id = 3 then X else NULL end) as X3,
       max(case when id = 4 then X else NULL end) as X4
from table 
group by PersonID;
```

I you are concerned about *writing* the code, just put the list of ids in a spreadsheet, use a formula to generate the appropriate code, and copy that back into your SQL query.

If you have an unknown number of ids, you might then need to use dynamic SQL.  Alternatively, you could concatenate the values together:

```
select PersonID, 
       group_concat(x order by id) as xs
from table 
group by PersonID;
```

Comment: For 700 values, this has got to be bonkers